# Sublime Text 3 plugin Anaconda can't do multiple-line lint

Tags: python, sublimetext, lint

I am using Sublime Text 3 (build 3047) using package control and the newest Anaconda plugin for python development. However I am facing a rather odd issue.

Using the default linter included in anaconda (not pylint), the plugin only displays the very first error it encounters. 
So, if for example I am having errors in line 3, 5 and 10, only line number 3 will be highlighted. PEP8 is also currently disabled.

Is there any way to work around this problem and show all errors in a file at once?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason that you don't get any more errors linted in the buffer. The only thing that come to my mind is a possible incompatibility with any other ST3 plugin that you have installed as well.

You can do several things to try to figure out what can be wrong:

1) Take a look at the Sublime Text console to see if there are errors raised by Anaconda or other plugin
2) Take a look at your Anaconda JsonServer logs, you can fin them on: `$HOME/Library/Caches/Jedi` on Mac OS X, `$HOME/.cache/jedi` on GNU/Linux or `%APP_DATA%\Jedi\Jedi` on Windows.

You can get some support as well just joining the Anaconda mailing list at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/anaconda-st3-plugin or just opening a new ticket in the project GitHub site: https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/issues